# Assign a new polymorphic association with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm trying to modify my active admin User form to modify a User's Role. The roles are a polymorphic association via role_assignments table.

When I submit the form, the roles are not updated, I guess because the attributes of the association are being protected and I'm not using permit_params the right way.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :newsletter_subscription, :password, :password_confirmation,
                role_assignment_attributes: [:role_id, :user_id, :_destroy, :_create]
  ...
end
```

Any ideas? Additional info:

Schema:

```
create_table "role_assignments", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "role_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The classes are simple:

```
class RoleAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :role_assignments
  has_many :users, through: :role_assignments
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This works find and gives me a nice form for modifying the roles. Active admin form for User:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do
    f.input :email
    f.input :newsletter_subscription, :as => :radio
    f.input :roles, :as => :check_boxes
  end
end
```

However, when I submit the form, nothing is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Like the [docs illustrate](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/3f242fc5ac8968e4cb8a8eb9f9a956d14e6b7eba/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters), you need to pass `:id` as a permitted parameter inside `:role_assignment_attributes`

```
permit_params :email, :newsletter_subscription, :password, :password_confirmation,
              role_assignment_attributes: [:id, :role_id, :user_id, :_destroy]
```

Note that I removed the `:_create` param, as I've never seen anything like that, so I'm assuming it was added unintentionally.